# Как ускорить работу парсера?

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

Делаю парсер, которые должен слить более 10к товаров. При каждом выполнение скрипта проходит по 20 следующим товаром.

Для парсинга использую cURL (получаю HTML код), и Simple HTML Dom Parser  (выборка нужных блоков).

Парсер построен так:
cURL'ом получаю HTML код страницы каталога с товаром, передаю разметку в HTML Dom Parser:

```
 $html = str_get_html($html_code);
 $srt_links = $html->find('.block');
```

Тут приходит 20 блоков, поэтому использую:

```
foreach ($srt_links as & $value) {

}
```

чтобы работать со всеми 20-тью блоками.

После идет парсинг каждого товара, то есть получает код 20-ти страниц:

```
foreach ($srt_links as & $value) { 
    $product = curl($value->href);
    $product_code = str_get_html($product);
    //и тут передаю HTML код страницы товара в Simple HTML Dom Parser чтобы делать выборку по блокам нужной информации.
}
```

Таким образом получается что парсер переходит и получает сразу HTML код 21 страницы (1 каталог товара + 20 страниц самх товаров).
Парсер выполняется около 15 секунд, что очень долго.

Что я делаю не правильно? Как можно ускорить работу парсера?

Comment: Так у вас не параллельно а по очереди страницы грузятся, думаю тут проблема только в скорости ответа удаленного сервера.

Comment: Если админы жадные :), то переходите на чистые регулярки, так как вы однотипную информацию со страницы берете. А если без парсера не можете, то посмотрите сравнение https://github.com/Imangazaliev/DiDOM/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-(1.6.3)

Comment: Парсер должен быть именно на PHP ?

Comment: вы сначала найдите узкое место в коде, потом уже вопросы задавайте. таймером засеките, сколько времени требуется на получение страницы, сколько на обработку для начала.

Answer (score 1):

В вашей программе, как я понимаю, все время уходит на последовательные запросы к ресурсу, а на сам парсинг уходит лишь малая часть времени. Поэтому надо смотреть в сторону распараллеливания.

Попробуйте переделать свой код под `multicurl`,тогда запросы будут выполняться быстрее. Ссылка на гитхаб - [тыц](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/blob/master/src/Curl/MultiCurl.php)

Comment: Интересный инструмент этот multicurl!